# python 3 passing value from function to main

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Im still really new to python3 and could use a little help
I would like variable a to be printed showing the area of a circle in the following code

```
from math import pi

def area(r):
    a = pi * r**2
    return a

if __name__ '__main__':
    r = int(input("Enter the Radius: "))
    area(r)
    print(a)
```

now i know that a is not defined and if i define it as a global variable and give it 0 it
it dose not return what i want  obviosly 
so my question is how do i fix this  im sure its something really simple

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
a = area(r)
```

The variable `a` is local inside `area()` function, so you can not use the variable outside it. But since you return the value, wherever you call `area(r)`, this is an expression whose value is what is returned inside the function, so it will evaluate to the original `a`.

When you type `a = area(r)`, you will give to a new local variable called `a` the value of `area(r)`, which is the value you passed to `return` inside the function. You could as well do simply:

```
r = int(input("Enter the Radius: "))
print(area(r))
```